# Javascript Drop Down Menu Won't Slide Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, slidedown

I'm developing a drop down menu with, essentially, two items; my design work, and my development work. Keep in mind this is for a web design class.

In one of the requirements, we're needing to design a "cool drop down menu." I have the HTML below setting up the menus.

```
    <div class="drop-down" align="center">
    <div class="design"><br><br><a href="http://corymeeks.tk/design.php"><p>Design</p></a></div>
    <div class="development"><br><br><a href="http://corymeeks.tk/design.php"><p>Development</p></a></div>
    </div>
```

My Javascript is shown below

```
   $(document).ready(function(){                    
   $(".drop-down").hide();                      
   $(".drop-down-button").click(function(){ 
       $(".drop-down").slideDown("active");         
   });                                          
});
```

I'm getting the drop down to work, but for whatever reason the drop down menu pops right back up when the JS loads. Is that something to do with me not forcing the "drop-down" from hide() to show()?

Once again, sorry for the n00b question.

Comment: where do you want this selector in that menu?> .drop-down-button

Answer (score 1):

In my example your code works well. Maybe you have an error in javascript which you didn't notice. Maybe you forgot to include jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){                    
   $(".drop-down").hide();    
    
    var isDroppedDown = false;
    
   $(".drop-down-button").click(function(){ 
       
       if(isDroppedDown){
           $(".drop-down").slideUp("active");     
           isDroppedDown = false;
       }else{
           $(".drop-down").slideDown("active");  
           isDroppedDown = true;
       }
       
       
              
   });                                          
});
```

```css
.drop-down
{
    background-color: #8787cc;
    display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="drop-down-button">Drop it!</div>

<div class="drop-down" align="center">
    <div class="design"><br><br><a href="http://corymeeks.tk/design.php"><p>Design</p></a></div>
    <div class="development"><br><br><a href="http://corymeeks.tk/design.php"><p>Development</p></a><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that was it. Thanks for suggesting that.